# For unique value of column 2 calculate average of all corresponding values of column 11 and 17 in linux

Tags: linux, bash, awk

Script in Linux platform:

```
zgrep "Storage Summary" /Storage/log/spoold/spoold.log.1.bz2|awk '{print $1, $2, $11, $17}'| sort -u
```

O/p :

```
November 19 27572.22 82.28
November 19 27585.55 82.32
November 19 27603.04 82.37
November 19 27611.72 82.40
November 19 27618.48 82.42
November 20 27631.96 82.46
November 20 27633.70 82.46
November 21 27645.05 82.50
November 21 27651.01 82.51
November 21 27652.94 82.52
November 21 27659.65 82.54
November 21 27674.55 82.58
November 21 27684.02 82.61
November 21 27691.34 82.63
November 21 27691.52 82.63
November 21 27697.52 82.65
November 22 27705.91 82.68
November 22 27729.71 82.75
November 22 27733.09 82.76
November 22 27770.01 82.87
```

I need output like

For each occurrence of `$2`(for everyday), calculate Avg of `$11` & `$17` and then print o/p as`print $1, $2, $11, $17`

Answer (score 3):

```
zgrep "Storage Summary" /Storage/log/spoold/spoold.log.1.bz2 | awk '
    { date=$1 " " $2; used[date] += $11; usedp[date] += $17; count[date]++; }
    END { for (d in used) { print d, used[d]/count[d], usedp[d]/count[d] } }
    '
```

For each unique date, this totals up the space used and the space used percentage, keeps count of the number of entries, and when it's done it prints out the averages (total/number_of_entries).
(I used both $1 and $2 as the date, in case you want to use this over more than one month).